# class 'boost ::shared_ptr<T>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'boost::signals::connection'

Tags: visual-c++, warnings, boost-signals

I get the following error on compiling the code.

```
c:\boost_1_48_0\boost\signals\connection.hpp(118) : warning C4251: 'boost::signals::connection::con' : class 'boost
::shared_ptr<T>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'boost::signals::connection'
```

The signals in the code are defined as

```
boost::signal<void (long long int)> totalTimeChanged;
boost::signal<void (unsigned int)> curTimeChanged;
```

connection is done as

```
GStreamer::totalTimeChanged.connect(boost::bind(&MainWindow\
            ::total_time_changed, &player, _1));
```

The compilation is successful but how do I get rid of these compiler warnings ?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to read [How can I use Standard Library (STL) classes in my dll interface or ABI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661738/common-practice-in-dealing-with-warning-c4251-class-needs-to-have-dll-inter) The mentioned 'UnknownRoad' posting is at http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/VisualStudio/warningC4251.html

HTH