# Why will I have a runtime check failure error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I did not realize in a .dll library object types that depends on things that happen at compile time can  case problems until I read the question [Could I ignore C4251 warning in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362415/could-i-ignore-c4251-warning-in-this-case/16362751#16362751) In deed, if the library compilation settings for the library and the program that uses the library are different, some errors can occur. Here is an example:

dll.h

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    class __declspec(dllexport) HelloWorld
    {
    public:
    #ifdef DTEST
      int test;
    #endif
      HelloWorld();

    };
```

dll.cpp

```
#include "dll.h"

HelloWorld::HelloWorld()
{
#ifdef DTEST
    test=0;
#endif
}
```

exe.cpp

```
#include "dll.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  HelloWorld myworld;

  return 0;
}
```

If I compile dll.h and dll.cpp to create dll.lib and dll.dll with the definition of DTEST but compile exe.cpp without the definition of DTEST. I will have a  runtime check failure #2 error. Could some explain why I have this error. Thanks!

Comment: Did you expect your program to run? How would you justify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this error because `DTEST` is a preprocessor macro and you are not defining it consistently for all pieces of your program.  It is completely removed by the time your code reaches the actual compiler, so the compiler won't catch the problem.  If you define `DTEST` for `dll.cpp` but not for `exe.cpp`, then `exe.cpp` will look like this to the compiler:

```
(...contents of <iostream>...)
(...contents of <string>...)

using namespace std;

class __declspec(dllexport) HelloWorld
{
public:
  HelloWorld();

};

(...contents of <iostream> again...)
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  HelloWorld myworld;

  return 0;
}
```

However, `dll.cpp` will look like this:

```
(...contents of <iostream>...)
(...contents of <string>...)

using namespace std;

class __declspec(dllexport) HelloWorld
{
public:
  int test;
  HelloWorld();

};

HelloWorld::HelloWorld()
{
    test=0;
}
```

The problem here is `dll.cpp` and `exe.cpp` have two different ideas of what `HelloWorld` is: `dll.cpp` thinks it contains `test`, but `exe.cpp` thinks it doesn't.  There is a runtime check that catches this mismatch, which is what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

What the compiler sees is the results of preprocessor expansion.
In your example, the compiler sees:

```
class HelloWorld
{
public:
    int test;
    HelloWorld();
};
```

in `dll.cpp`, and

```
class HelloWorld
{
public:
    HelloWorld();
};
```

in `exe.cpp`.  Same class, two different definitions.  That's
a violation of the one definition rule, which results in
undefined behavior.

This has nothing to do with the C4251 warning (which if
I understand correctly, only concerns linking between different
DLLs).